# Efficiently keeping elements in a list (an input list) that exist in another list (a keep list)

Tags: list-manipulation

I have some code that generates lists of integers (one such list is called, for example, `inputList`).  I also have a "master list" of integers that should be kept, if present, in `keepList`.

I would like to write a function `keepElements` that keeps integers in `inputList` that exist in `keepList`.  Alternatively, I could write a function `removeElements` that removes elements from `inputList` that do *not* exist in `keepList`.  Since `keepElements` and `removeElements` generate the same output list, I will use whichever is faster.

Below is a sort of minimal working example.  In the first section of code, I generate `inputList` and `keepList` (I have used `RandomInteger` in this example, just to generate `keepList`).  Note that even in my actual code, `inputList` and `keepList` are both in sorted ascending order.  I have written `keepElements` and `removeElements`, but I am wondering if you can please help me make them faster.  I will need to run either function approximately 200,000 times, so this can quite expensive and I would like to minimize the cost as much as possible.

Do you have any advice?  Using `Position` is probably relatively expensive, so I should perhaps avoid using it.  Thank you for your time!

```
minVal = 1;
maxVal = 1000;
inputList = Range[minVal, maxVal];
keepList = 
  DeleteDuplicates[
   Sort[Table[RandomInteger[{minVal, maxVal}], {500}]]];

keepElements[inputList_, keepList_] := Module[{position},
  position = 
   Flatten[Position[inputList, _?(MemberQ[keepList, #] &), {1}, 
     Heads -> False]];
  inputList[[position]]
  ]
keepElements[inputList, keepList] // Timing // First

removeElements[inputList_, keepList_] := 
 DeleteCases[inputList, _?(! MemberQ[keepList, #] &)]
removeElements[inputList, keepList] // Timing // First
```

which on my machine gives the output:

> 0.031
>
> 0.016

Comment: Much faster: keepElements2[inputList_, keepList_] := 
 Cases[inputList, Alternatives @@ keepList]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`Intersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Intersection.html):

[image]

Since you say that your lists are already sorted, this will probably be the most efficient solution. All you need to do is:

```
Intersection[inputList, keepList]
```

Compare with your solutions:

```
keepElements[inputList, keepList] == 
removeElements[inputList, keepList] == 
Intersection[inputList, keepList]
(* True *)
```

and the timings:

```
keepElements[inputList, keepList]; // Timing // First
removeElements[inputList, keepList]; // Timing // First
Intersection[inputList, keepList]; // Timing // First

(* 0.008921    
   0.012487    
   0.000035 *)
```

Comment: beat me by a toad's jump

Comment: I was about to answer that

Comment: @Rojo I was in the queue first

Comment: @Verde, it's a stack so I'm first